# Parsing a string into multiple separate strings

Tags: c#, string, parsing

Hey guys I have a quick question. I am trying to parse a single string into multiple strings using a keyword. I can currently find a set of code that allows me to parse the single string but I need to store each of the new strings as a new variable/item.

```
string full = "Hey//Please//Help";
```

parse into:

first string- Hey

Second string- Please

third string- Help

So for example I would like to manipulate the first string, Hey, by itself.  Please let me know if any more explanation is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Simple [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.String.Split);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true):

```
string[] results = full.Split(new string[] { "//" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach(string str in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

**Result:**

```
Hey
Please
Help
```

Comment: @un-lucky You could have just noted that out in a comment instead of down-voting the whole answer, while it generated the excepted result needed by the user

Comment: @un-lucky these are (imho) no down-vote reasons, the space is no syntactical problem, neither the superfluos `@`. The answer is correct and well explaining, I don't see a reason to downvote.

Comment: @RenéVogt: You may look after edit, I just down-voted to let him modify the answer. Now it is Fine and perfect answer.